# How to install regular version (not preview) of Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, installation, vsinstaller

I'm trying to install regular version (not preview) of Visual Studio Community by using Visual Studio Intaller. In it, I can see list of versions that are installed and available, but all of these versions are preview. My installed versions are Visual Studio Community 2017 Preview and Visual Studio Community 2019 Preview. Versions that are available to be installed are Visual Studio Enterprise and Professional 2017 and 2019 Preview.

How can I install Visual Studio Community 2017 (or 2019) that is not preview version?

Comment: Hi, have you tried download the VS community 2017 installer from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/ and run it to install? If this issue persists, could you please share the VS installer interface in here? I will check the installer version is the latest version or not.

Comment: @SaraLiu-MSFT When I tried installer from the given link, community version became available. I think I had latest version of installer, but that version didn't contain versions that are not preview. Problem is solved. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Uros, I am so glad to hear that your issue is solved, could you please mark my reply when you have free time? That will help other community members to easier search this information, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please download [the VS community 2017 installer](http://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads) and run this installer as administrator, then check the available version again.